# Reassigning left Win key + Tab to left control + tilde?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I want to reassign the `left Windows key + Tab` to `left control + tilde` permanently throughout the windows environment. Ideally I would hope to do that without third party software (e.g tweaking windows registry).

If this is not possible, I am already aware for an alternative called Autohotkey. I tried this software using an AHK file with just a line like::

```
$<#Tab::<^`
```

but it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add the clarification from your comment below the answer, that you want to remap a key combination instead of individual keys. Please also add some background information for what purpose you need this. Whether it is possible or not may depend on the way how the application checks for the keyboard input. (Does it read a character or does it read key press events and/or modifier state.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Send](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Send.htm) command:

```
$<#Tab::Send <^`
```

or

```
$<#Tab::Send {Ctrl Down}`{Ctrl Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of software out there that helps you remap the keys via the registry. Once you set the remap in the software you won't need to keep it running, since it actually set the changes in the registry. Have a look at this page for some examples: https://www.ghacks.net/2010/06/06/the-ultimate-guide-to-keyboard-remapping

Comment: I am not sure this answers my question. The utilities cited in the link can only remap one key at a time, not a combination as I want. Unless I 've got it wrong. Have I?

Comment: @uft12 You'd have to dig into the programs' features yourself to know for sure; I've never personally needed to remap keys (other than my custom Logitech game keyboard with a bunch of extra keys on it, in which case I just  use the Logitech software for it). Remember, there're tons of other programs out there besides the specific ones listed on that one page. Alternativeto.net can be a useful resource for that.